# Make all TextBoxes UPPERCASE

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way i can make all `TextBoxes` in a `Form` UPPERCASE.
What i have been doing is

```
txtPersonName.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
....;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot set this at design time?

Comment: When do you want the text to become upper case? After it loses focus?

Comment: Yes,  when i move to the next `TextBox`

Comment: This will hopefully help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444562/convert-text-to-uppercase-while-typing-in-text-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all TextBox controls in Controls collection of `Form` and set the CharacterCasing property to `CharacterCasing.Upper`

```
foreach(var tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    tb.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when i `TAB` to another `TextBox` the previous text does not change to uppercase?

Comment: if you do this code after `Initialize()`, all textboxes will always be uppercase.

Comment: Please explain how you use the code and what step you take and where it fails