# Visual Studio IntelliSense not showing Control.IsDisposed Property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have Visual Studio 2013 and I have noticed that it will not show `Control.IsDisposed` in IntelliSense. I am not sure whether this is the only thing that isn't displayed. Everything else seems to be shown fine in  IntelliSense.

[image]

I can use the `IsDisposed` property fine, it will build and execute fine. Is there any reason for this or any known fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Control.IsDisposed`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4d2f3937a840118b) property has the [`EditorBrowseableAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) set to `Advanced`, which makes it non-browsable in the VS editor:

> The property or method is a feature that only advanced users should
>   see. An editor can either show or hide such properties.

```
[
Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden),
SRDescription(SR.ControlDisposedDescr)
]
public bool IsDisposed {
    get {
        return GetState(STATE_DISPOSED);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

@Glen points out (thanks!) that you can view advanced members by changing the VS settings in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#:

[image: Advanced members]

Comment: Found this in the article that Yuval linked to above:

"In Visual C#, you can control when advanced properties appear in IntelliSense and the Properties Window with the Hide Advanced Members setting under Tools | Options | Text Editor | C#. The corresponding EditorBrowsableState is Advanced."

Comment: This seems odd to me. Does anyone know the reasoning behind hiding "advanced" members?

Comment: @KDecker [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27253880/1870803) has some info on when that's actually useful.

Comment: My guess for the reasoning: to show a shortened pick list that only includes the members that are used most of the time, and excludes the more "advanced" members, thus making it quicker to find a specific member (assuming it is on the list, that is).

Comment: @Polyfun That, and perhaps hiding "advanced" properties that new programmers would get confused of or mistakenly use.